# write message in whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, imacros

I'm tryin to write a message in https://web.whatsapp.com/
with iMacros, but I'm unable to do this.

This is my code so far:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://web.whatsapp.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=11974499488
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:+55<SP>11<SP>97449-9488

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:hi
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:icon<SP>icon-send<SP>compose-btn-send&&TX
```

How can I write a message from the code?

Here I needed to write myself a message and then click on the text box to send it.

Comment: You just should try to record the macro with 'Experimental event recording mode'.

Comment: Great! Thanks, it's working now